# Is there a language that has temporal noun modifiers?

Tags: nouns

I am not a linguist, so my question is most probably **very** poorly worded. I have obviously searched on google, but to no avail. Is there a language that has noun declensions or suffixes/affixes that place the noun in a specific point in time? I suspect that if such a language exists, it will probably be polysynthetic. Here are examples of what I'm trying to find:

- "I have the past-report" (I have [the report that *was*], I have [the old version])
- "I love past-you" (I love [the person that you *were*])
- "I am working the future-field" (I am working [the plot of land that *will be* the field])
- "I hoped to receive now-money" (I hoped to receive [the money that I have now received])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three examples come to mind. First, English "ex-", as in "My ex-boss", which puts the boss relationship in the fast (but it does entail that he is no longer my boss). If you aren't satisfied with that example, explaining why that doesn't count should clarify what you're really interested in. Second, in Lushootseed, the past and future clitics can be used on nominals, as in [tsi d-*tu*-čəgwas] "my former wife" [tsi d-*ɬu*-čəgwas] "my future wife". Unfortunately, there are no more fluent speakers, but John Lawler might be able to fill in details. And finally, Guarani has such constructions, discussed in [this paper](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/tonhauser.1/papers/sub9tonhauser.pdf) by Judith Tonhauser, also discussing a paper by Nordlinger & Sadler in *Language* 80 which discusses the question in a number of other languages. Tonhauser, however, claims that these are nominal aspects, not tenses, and frankly the argument is kind of above my pay grade.

Comment: Robin Lakoff once told me that _ex-mother-in-law-to-be_ was her favorite English kinship term.

Comment: Thanks! Lushotseed seems interesting, but Guarani is closer to what I was looking for. I specifically did not include "ex-" in my examples, since the meaning is a bit different. "ex-" mainly describes a past relation. Consider this:

"My ex-book" (meaning "The book that was once mine" rather than "The [object] that was once a book").

Answer (score 1):

Kayardild and Lardil mark tense (time) in the verb, but also in the nouns by suffixes like *-(i)na* (past) in Kayardild:

- *Dangka-a burldi-jarra yarbuth-**ina** thabuju-karra-nguni-**na** wangal-nguni-**na*** “The man hit the bird with the brother's boomerang": *yarbuth* "bird", *thabuju-karra-nguni* "with brother's" and *nguni* "boomerang" are all marked for past tense. (*-jarra* is the verbal past marker.)

And *-kur* (future) or *-ngarr* (non-future) in Lardil:

- *Ngada bule-thur ya-**kur**.* "I will catch a fish."

(Sources: Strazny's *Encyclopedia of Linguistics*; Hale, *Damin and Lardil Phonotactics*, via wikipedia page on Lardil.)

Comment: I first heard about this on Evans' *Dying Words*, where I also learned about this fun quote from Pinker & Bloom's *Natural Language and Natural Selection*: *Indeed, though grammatical devices are put to different uses in different languages, the possible pairings are very circumscribed. **No language uses noun affixes to express tense** or elements with the syntactic privileges of auxiliaries to express the shape of the direct object*…